# Porque não se pode deixar comentários no perfil?

Tags: debate, perfil

Sempre tive essa duvida, sim eu sei, o `SO` é como um *wiki da programação* e assuntos diversos.

- Mas porque não podemos contatar outro usuário diretamente no perfil pessoal?
- Alguma comunidade do `SO` suporta esta funcionalidade?

Acredito que outros também devam ter essa curiosidade, apenas para fins de conhecimento.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Eu não acho que o SO seja "como um *wiki da programação* e assuntos diversos". Mas ele certamente foi projetado para que cada pessoa se comunique preferencialmente com **grupos** de outras pessoas, e não com **uma** outra pessoa diretamente.

Quanto mais uma pessoa fala diretamente com a outra, menor a chance de o conteúdo da conversa ser relevante para outras pessoas. O site procura diminuir a dispersão do conteúdo e maximizar sua coesão, para assim tentar atingir mais gente de uma só vez. Se a comunicação direta com outros usuários fosse implementada, mesmo que apenas no perfil, isso aumentaria a dispersão - pense na quantidade de notificações que alguns usuários passariam a receber todos os dias.

O lugar onde esse tipo de interação pode acontecer é o [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/), que é relativamente independente do site, e onde só participa quem quer. Assim, quem deseja compartilhar conhecimento mas não quer atender demandas individuais tem o seu espaço preservado.

Comment: De acordo com [Asking for help via email](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297249/asking-for-help-via-email), oferecer ajuda "one on one" não é proibido.

Comment: Não é proibido, mas não é incentivado. E se uma pergunta se transforma em uma seção de "one on one" fora do site, e fica sem uma resposta aqui, ela perde o sentido, e deverá ser fechada e possivelmente excluída.